# Specify length parameters for attributes in Waterline ORM

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

How in Waterline can we specify types say DECIMAL(10,2) for currency? I can see that we can give it a type of decimal but this will use default length information - how do we limit the size of fields? I appreciate that some databases won't support lengths etc but surely that doesn't mean we can't allow it to be specified for those that do.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the size of fields in general using "size", e.g:

```
     attributes: {
       name: {
          type: 'string',
          size: 255
       }
     }
```

And that works fine for strings.... Can't speak for other adapters but i would guess they will have the same problem, but with the sails-mysql adapter ther isn't an easy way to accomplish that as far as i can see.

Just take a look at sails-mysql/lib/sql.js (sqlTypeCast() function) and see what they do for strings vs what they do for floats.

You can always implement your adapter, implement a custom rule or change the DB manually if you need it to be reflected in the schema.

Hope that helps :)