# Specify length and scale parameters of decimal (numeric) data type in waterline orm (sails js)

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sqldatatypes, waterline

How to specify `decimal(length, scale)` as a columnType in waterline orm for a currency column? I could find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240549/specify-length-parameters-for-attributes-in-waterline-orm) question has been already asked. But the answer is not relevant to the question.

This is what the column attribute looks like. I'm using sails-Postgres.

```
attributes: { 
    price: {
        type: 'number',
        columnType: 'decimal(9,2)',
        columnName: 'PRICE'
       }
     }
```

[In sails documents](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes#columnType) they have mentioned that

> Column types are entirely database-dependent. Be sure that the `columnType` you select corresponds to a data type that is valid for your database! If you don’t specify a `columnType`, the adapter will choose one for you based on the attribute’s `type`.

But when I mentioned `columnType: 'decimal(9,2)'` (although it supports in Postgres) it does not properly work. When I retrieving data using blueprints it gives the price as a string.

```
{
    "price": "10.00",
}
```

I have read that these data types `­string, text, ­integer, float, date, ­dat­etime, ­boolean, ­binary, array, json, ­email` are supported by waterline. In that case what would be the best data type to store a currency value? If we choose the `float` data type, how to store the price as `decimal(9,2)`?

Any help would be much appriciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in this case is to specify the definition like so:

```js
 price: {
      type: 'number',
      defaultsTo: 34.99,
  },
```

Since I'm specifying a default price in here, Waterline will create a `float4` column type for that value.

It is also worthy of note that I will be converting that amount to center(by multiplying by 100) so What the database will store will be `3499` I find it okay to store this way because payment providers will be needing a cent amount any ways.

On the conversion, I find it suitable to do in a `beforeCreate` Waterline lifecycle callback. So something like this.

```js
beforeCreate: async function (valuesToSet, proceed) {
    // Compute amounts
    valuesToSet.price = sails.helpers.convertAmountToCent(valuesToSet.price)

    return proceed()
  },
```

> Also, Waterline set the column type to float4 because it is inferring that from the `defaultsTo` value of `34.99`